# How to access peekAll() in base.html.twig to check for messages/flashes

Tags: symfony, twig

In symfony 4.1

In the controler:

```
$this->addFlash(
    'notice',
    'Your changes were saved!'
);
 return $this->render(...);
```

Twig base template:

```
{% for message in app.flashes('notice') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

That works fine, but I want to wrap ALL messages in a div.  The below does not work:

```
{% if app.flashes is not empty %}
  <div id="messageBox" class="overlay">
    <div class="message" onclick="slide(document.querySelector('#messageBox')); this.classList.add('fadeAway');">
      {% for label, messages in app.flashes %}
        <section class="{{ label }}">
          <p><b>{{ label }}</b></p>
          <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
              <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </section>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

The problem is that the line `{% if app.flashes is not empty %}` erases the messages, so the following for loops and empty result.

How do I use `peekAll()` for the `if` logic?

Comment: It would seem that the act of accessing app.flashes removes them from the set of flashes. Perhaps you could retrieve them into a non-volatile, local structure before evaluating them.

Comment: Maybe this blog post helps you (if you use symfony > 3.2) https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-improved-flash-messages (look the last part with the for loop)

Comment: checking with `{% if app.session.flashbag.all is not empty %}` has the same effect - I'll stick with my answer for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to check with `peekAll()` is `{% if app.session.flashbag.peekAll() is not empty %}`  This will not clear the flashBag as per documentation.

Comment: found answer in [SymfonCasts](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/flash-messages#peeking-at-the-flash-messages)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the best way to do this, but the following is my solution.

In the base.html.twig:

```
{% set flashes = app.flashes %}
{% if flashes is not empty %}
  <div id="messageBox" class="overlay">
    <div class="message" onclick="slide(document.querySelector('#messageBox')); this.classList.add('fadeAway');">
      {% for label, messages in flashes %}
        <section class="{{ label }}">
          <p><b>{{ label }}</b></p>
          <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
              <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </section>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Basically, set the returned value of `app.flashes` to `flashes` and handle that.